# Jade get nodejs view using localStorage

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, passport.js

am using nodejs backend with jade for views and passportJS to auth the request

i have some service in nodejs that render a view like below:-

```
index.get('/',passport.authenticate('token'),function (req,res,next) {


console.log("++++++++"+JSON.stringify(req.headers));

res.render('login');
```

});

so i want to send a header (token) from jade to service then render the view

is there any way to do that ?!

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not from within the Jade template, but you can just prior to res.render using

```
 res.set(field, [value])
```

which is aliased to

```
res.header(field, [value])
```

So for your case, it would look something like:

```
res.header('Authorization', 'Bearer xxxxxxxx');
res.render('login');
```

See [ExpressJS res.set](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.set).